# Jquery getting undefined value of the closest class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to do validation comparing a pair of datetime values. I created a dynamic form by which everytime user click on the "Add Session" button. A session form div will be appended. For eg, I am trying to add 2 sessions and validate 2 pairs of session datetime values with the codes below.

```
    $('.startdatetime').each(function(){
        console.log($(this).val());
        console.log($(this).closest('.datetime-div').next().find('.enddatetime').val());
        if($(this).val() === "" || $(this).val() === null ){
            $(this).closest('.startdatetime-input').after("<p class='error-message font-bold col-pink'>Start Date Time is required.<p>");
            hasErr = true;
        }else if(moment($(this).val()).isSameOrAfter($(this).closest('.datetime-div').next().find('.enddatetime').val(), 'minute')){ //validate start datetime < end datetime
            $(this).closest('.startdatetime-input').after("<p class='error-message font-bold col-pink'>Invalid Date Time.<p>");
            hasErr = true;
        }
    });
```

I am getting undefined value for the first session end datetime in first loop which I am debugging using console.log.

Codes below show my html snippet.

```
              <div class="row">
                <div class="datetime-div col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="form-line startdatetime-input">
                            <label>Start Date Time</label>
                            <input type="text" class="datetimepicker form-control startdatetime" placeholder="Please choose date & time...">
                        </div>
                    </div>                    
                </div>
                <div class="datetime-div col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="form-line enddatetime-input">
                            <label>End Date Time</label>
                            <input type="text" class="datetimepicker form-control enddatetime" placeholder="Please choose date & time...">
                        </div>
                    </div>                    
                </div>
            </div>
```

```js
$('.startdatetime').each(function() {
  console.log($(this).val());
  console.log($(this).closest('.datetime-div').next().find('.enddatetime').val());
  if ($(this).val() === "" || $(this).val() === null) {
    $(this).closest('.startdatetime-input').after("<p class='error-message font-bold col-pink'>Start Date Time is required.<p>");
    hasErr = true;
  } else if (moment($(this).val()).isSameOrAfter($(this).closest('.datetime-div').next().find('.enddatetime').val(), 'minute')) { //validate start datetime < end datetime
    $(this).closest('.startdatetime-input').after("<p class='error-message font-bold col-pink'>Invalid Date Time.<p>");
    hasErr = true;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="datetime-div col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="form-line startdatetime-input">
        <label>Start Date Time</label>
        <input type="text" class="datetimepicker form-control startdatetime" placeholder="Please choose date & time...">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="datetime-div col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="form-line enddatetime-input">
        <label>End Date Time</label>
        <input type="text" class="datetimepicker form-control enddatetime" placeholder="Please choose date & time...">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any idea of getting the closest enddatetime value with the most appropriate jQuery selector?

Comment: See the snippet from your provided code - seems to be finding the `.closest` just fine?

Comment: but i am getting end datetime value of undefined in the first console.

Comment: Run the snippet. There is no `undefined`.

Comment: is there any other jQuery selectors or methods that can be used for getting the value?

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks fine in your code. You are not getting an `undefined`, you are getting an empty value because both inputs are empty. If you fill the attribute `value`, you will get those values printed in the console, run the code snippet I share and check. My changes are in the html `input` elements. So it seems that you should be running the javascript you shared once the user has filled the inputs, not before like in the code snippet you shared.

```js
$('.startdatetime').each(function() {
  console.log($(this).val());
  console.log($(this).closest('.datetime-div').next().find('.enddatetime').val());
  if ($(this).val() === "" || $(this).val() === null) {
    $(this).closest('.startdatetime-input').after("<p class='error-message font-bold col-pink'>Start Date Time is required.<p>");
    hasErr = true;
  } else if (moment($(this).val()).isSameOrAfter($(this).closest('.datetime-div').next().find('.enddatetime').val(), 'minute')) { //validate start datetime < end datetime
    $(this).closest('.startdatetime-input').after("<p class='error-message font-bold col-pink'>Invalid Date Time.<p>");
    hasErr = true;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="datetime-div col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="form-line startdatetime-input">
        <label>Start Date Time</label>
        <input type="text" value="valueForStartDateTime" class="datetimepicker form-control startdatetime" placeholder="Please choose date & time...">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="datetime-div col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="form-line enddatetime-input">
        <label>End Date Time</label>
        <input type="text" value="valueForEndDateTime" class="datetimepicker form-control enddatetime" placeholder="Please choose date & time...">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```